# Casting structs to the pointers

Tags: c, struct, casting, packet

For a couple of days now I'm working with packets on c, I have successfully created icmp packet to send, but I didn't get the way to put it into the socket by myself, so I have found multiple codes that should perform similar action. So they all contain the part that I don't understand completely and I can't find any information about it. They are casting structures with packet to a char pointer, something like this:

```
    static char *packet;
    ip= (struct iphdr*) packet;
    icmp= (struct icmphdr*)(ip+1);
```

When I have tried this I have got the segmentation fault. Please explain to me the purpose of casting structures and why the same piece of code doesn't work in my case. Thank you.

*EDITED*

```
struct iphdr *ip;
struct icmphdr *icmp;

ip=malloc(sizeof(*ip));
icmp=malloc(sizeof(*icmp));

int sock;

uint16_t psize = sizeof(*icmp)+sizeof(*ip);
static char *packet;
ip= (struct iphdr*) packet;
icmp= (struct icmphdr*)(ip+1);

unsigned int id = (unsigned int)rand();
unsigned int seq = (unsigned int)rand();

ip->version = 4;
ip->ihl = 5;
ip->tos = 0;
ip->tot_len = htons(psize);
ip->id = id;
ip->frag_off = 0;
ip->ttl = 255;
ip->protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP;
ip->saddr = subnet.ipDec;
icmp->type = 8;
icmp->code = 0;
icmp->un.echo.id=id;
icmp->un.echo.sequence=seq;
icmp->checksum=0;

sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
struct sockaddr_in destIP;
destIP.sin_family=AF_INET;
uint32_t destIPDec=0;
ip->daddr = destIPDec;
destIP.sin_addr.s_addr=destIPDec;
sendto(sock, packet, psize, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &destIP, sizeof(destIP));
```

Comment: Show more code, with 3 lines of code we cannot help.

Comment: I have added the full part with the icmp packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a `packet` you must **one** chunk of assign memory to it and not to the 'sub structues'. You have

```
ip=malloc(sizeof(*ip));
icmp=malloc(sizeof(*icmp));

int sock;

uint16_t psize = sizeof(*icmp)+sizeof(*ip);
static char *packet;
ip= (struct iphdr*) packet;     // here you access undefined pointer packet; previous contents of ip is lost
icmp= (struct icmphdr*)(ip+1);  // same for icmp
```

remove te `malloc()`s you have and change it to

```
 ----
 static char *packet;

 packet = malloc( sizeof *ip  + sizeof *icmp );
 ip= (struct iphdr*) packet;  
 icmp= (struct icmphdr*)(ip+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a basic mistake in your code.

Here you allocate memory for two variables

```
ip=malloc(sizeof(*ip));
icmp=malloc(sizeof(*icmp));
```

but soon after you do

```
static char *packet;
ip= (struct iphdr*) packet;
icmp= (struct icmphdr*)(ip+1);
```

So `ip` and `icmp` is no longer pointing to the allocated memory. Instead you have assigned them the value of an uninitialized variable, i.e. `packet`. That is undefined behavior and explains the seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

The issue happens when you're assigning values to `ip` and `icmp`. I recommend the following code:

```
struct packet {
    struct iphdr ip;
    struct icmphdr icmp;
} myPacket;

myPacket = (struct packet*)malloc( sizeof(struct packet) );

ip =(struct iphdr*) &packet.ip;  
icmp = (struct icmphdr*) &packet.icmp;
```